# What is the difference between hide and unselecting 'enable load'?

Tags: powerbi

What is the difference between hide and unselecting 'enable load'? Both options result in the table/field not showing up on the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about the report. It's also about efficiency and storage.

There are situations when queries serve as intermediary data sources, which are only used for joins into other tables and after that are not required for any visuals. In that case, you don't need to load the table into the data model at all and the data in that table will not use up space in the data model.

This helps keep the data model cleaner and the PBIX file smaller. Hiding tables from the report does not do that.

**Edit after comment:** Here is a scenario where I would disable data load of a query: Say I have a customer table with customer ID, name, region and a hundred other columns. It has 100,000 customers, most of them are historic, only 10,000 are active. In my Transaction table I have only the customer ID, but I want to report by the region.

I can load the customer table into Power Query, then join it to the Transaction table and keep only the region in the Transaction table. I don't need any other details from the customer table because all my reporting only drills down to region level, not individual customer. Also my report is focused on a segment of my business that involves only a fraction of my existing customers. Therefore, I don't need the whole customer table in the data model. I save the Customer query as a connection only, and don't load it into the data model to save the space.

Yes, I could load it and I could use a relationships instead of the join, but by loading just the region field for a subset of customers, I can keep the model much leaner.

Comment: Please can you give example of "only used for joins into other tables and after that are not required for any visuals". When a table is used in join then why not refresh its data?

Comment: I added a use case to my answer.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the tour. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: 1. The 1GB limit for PRO account is for data retrieved by query editor or is it for the data loaded into the model? 2. In your example, you are joining customer with transaction table and using only region. So if you disable the load then will region value be available to the model? Confused since region is located on customer table.

Comment: I just explained that I joined the customer table with the transaction table and keep the region. Hence the region is now in the transaction table. I thought with your SQL background that would be a no-brainer.

Comment: Did you mean join in sql query of the query editor or join as in creating a relationship between the tables? Confused about what "keep the region " means

Comment: The ribbon command in Power Query is "Merge". It performs a Join operation like in SQL, based on a key and you define what kind of join you want to do, i.e. left, right. Have you never used that? Try it. It might help you understand better what's going on. After the Merge/Join, you need to expand the table column that is the result of the Merge/Join and select which columns of the joined table you want to keep, i.e. add as columns to the current query.  [...]

Comment: [...] In my scenario, I keep just the region, which will then be a column in the Power Query.  After that, I no longer need the Customer table, so I never need to load it into the data model. 
You really should just have a play with Power Query to better understand how it works. Your questions sound very academic and theoretical, especially if you haven't worked with aspects like merging queries.

Comment: Ah with the word merge now it all makes sense. Thanks